# How to use knowledge of sensor noise

Tags: sensors, sensor-fusion, uncertainty

Reasoning about the meaning of uncertainty of sensor measurement I ran into a doubt:

(1) When we talk about sensor uncertainty, we often model it as a Gaussian distribution $\mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{z}, \Sigma)$, where $\boldsymbol{z}$ is the value measured by the sensor and the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ gives us information about the uncertainty. In particular, $\Sigma$ represents the uncertainty on "how" far the true value $\boldsymbol{x}$ is from $\boldsymbol{z}$. The distribution is centered on $\boldsymbol{z}$ as we do not have access to the true value $\boldsymbol{x}$.

(2) Now, assume that we have access to the ground truth, and we learn the distribution of the error, such that $\boldsymbol{z} = \boldsymbol{x} + \boldsymbol{\epsilon}$ where $\boldsymbol{\epsilon} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \hat{\Sigma})$.

The two situations might look the same, but in (1) the distribution $\mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{z}, \Sigma)$ is centered on the **measured value**, while in (2) $\hat{\Sigma}$ is the covariance of a Gaussian centered on the **true value**. Is my interpretation of (1) correct? Can we set $\Sigma = \hat{\Sigma}$, i.e. can we use the covariance learned in (2) in the setting described in (1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. It's just a matter of interpretation.

(1) is the guess on the location of the true value whereas (2) is simulating your sensor behavior.

Your equation in (1) can be converted to N(z,sigma) = z + N(0,sigma) witch is eventually same as your second equation.

Can we set Σ=Σ^, i.e. can we use the covariance learned in (2) in the setting described in (1)?

-> This depends on your system definition. In many cases, Σ^ is not available. So sometimes we just use the manufacture's sensor noise model or we just manually calculate them which might be different from the real true ground truth. But if you are running a simulation they will be identical.

Answer (score 1):

It may be worth noting that $\Sigma$ does not just describe "how far" the true value $\boldsymbol{x}$ is from $\boldsymbol{z}$ , but "where" in relation to it, the difference is apparent when the distribution is not 'circular' in the multidimensional case.

Also, a Gaussian is a symmetric distribution, and only under that condition the same $\Sigma$ can be used in (1) and (2).

If the model was not a symmetric distribution (implying it is not a Gaussian), e.g. in a 1D case the distribution would require mirroring along the vertical axis between cases (1) and (2): if $\boldsymbol{z}$ is more likely to be to the left of the true $\boldsymbol{x}$ than to the right, the inferred $\boldsymbol{x}$ would be more likely to be to the right of the observed $\boldsymbol{z}$ ...